# How to align widgets with some position on background, and also display right on different devices?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext, android

I'm not a designer but recently, I have been asked to change Login Screen UI for the app of my company.

I have got a background image from a designer. This image is a complete login screen. That means it is a single PNG file with the Input Box (User Name and Password Box) DRAWN on it.

Of course even it looks like a complete Login screen, just put it there won't work since the input boxes are fake.

I tried to put the `EditText` widgets on it, tried to let it just on the position on the background image and set these two widgets background to none so the user won't see it. However, on difference devices it just displays incorrectly. Sometimes above the "background input box", sometimes below it. Anyway, it just won't fit there.

I wonder if there is a way that could let me solve this problem. Let the widgets will be on that exactly position of the background, no matter how the devices changes.

Here is my layout now, and hope it will help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pbackground"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtBxPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:height="33dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:width="160dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtBxUserID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtBxPassword"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtBxPassword"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:height="33dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:width="160dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here are the images I captured from Eclipse, as you can see I put two `EditText` boxes just at the position of the input boxes on background. But on the real devices, they will be misplaced.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

put the linearlayout as base layout instead of relative layout...
and use tablerow layout and place the widgets in it
wisely use android:layout_margin and android:layout_width and android:layout_height
properly...
hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your designer to give you files for the individual elements -- e.g. the padlock & head icons on their own, and the shaded box on its own. Convert the box to a [Nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and set it as the background drawable of a suitable layout element (i.e. the container layout of each row).

You will also want to have [multiple sizes of each image to support different pixel densities](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets).

If you don't do this, you will always have some devices where the screen looks terrible.